# Como guardar los datos de punteros y structs en un archivo .txt en C

Tags: c, archivo, txt, nodos

Estoy intentando hacer un inventario con punteros y nodos. Sin embargo, necesito que se guarde la información en un archivo. Logro crear el archivo pero no logro que los datos se guarden en dicho archivo si no que da otros numeros. Como puedo hacer para que si se copie la informacion que ingresa el usuario y se guarde en el archivo? Este archivo es formato .txt y deberia poder leerse despues pero eso ya es en segundo plano ya que lo que necesito es si poder guardarlos datos pero soy nueva con esto de los punteros y archivos.

````
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct RegistroProducto RegistroProducto;
struct RegistroProducto
{
  char Nombre[100];
  int Codigo;
  int Cantidad;
  float Precio;
  char Fecha[20];
  RegistroProducto *Siguiente;
};


typedef struct Lista Lista;
struct Lista
{
  RegistroProducto *Primero;
};


Lista *Inicialisacion()
{
  Lista *lista = malloc(sizeof(*lista));
  RegistroProducto *elemento = malloc(sizeof(*elemento));



  if (lista == NULL || elemento == NULL) //Si ocure un errror
  {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //Paramos el codigo
  }

  elemento->Nombre[100];
  elemento->Codigo = 0;
  elemento->Cantidad = 0;
  elemento->Precio = 0;
  elemento->Fecha[20];

  elemento->Siguiente = NULL;
  lista->Primero = elemento;

  return lista;
}

void Insercion(Lista *lista, char PdcNombre[100], char PdcFecha[20], int PdcCodigo, int PdcCantidad, float PdcPrecio)
{
  //Creacion del nuevo elemento
  RegistroProducto *nuevo = malloc(sizeof(*nuevo));


  if (lista == NULL || nuevo == NULL)
  {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  sprintf(nuevo->Nombre, PdcNombre);
  nuevo->Codigo = PdcCodigo;
  nuevo->Cantidad = PdcCantidad;
  nuevo->Precio = PdcPrecio;
  sprintf(nuevo->Fecha, PdcFecha);

  //Insercion del nuevo elemento
  nuevo->Siguiente = lista->Primero;
  lista->Primero = nuevo;

}


void PrintLista(Lista *lista)
{
  if (lista == NULL)
  {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  RegistroProducto *actual = lista->Primero;

  while (actual != NULL)
  {
      if (actual->Codigo == 0)
      {
        printf("\nFin del inventario.\n\n");
        break;
      }
      else
      {
      printf("Nombre: %s\n", actual->Nombre);
      printf("Codigo: %d\n", actual->Codigo);
      printf("Cantidad: %d\n", actual->Cantidad);
      printf("Precio: Q %0.2f \n", actual->Precio);
      printf("Fecha de primer ingreso del producto: %s\n", actual->Fecha);
      actual = actual->Siguiente;
      printf("\n");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
}



void Anadir(Lista *lista, int Sumar, int CantidadMas)
{
  RegistroProducto *NodoCorecto = lista->Primero;

  while (NodoCorecto != NULL)
  {
    if (NodoCorecto->Codigo == Sumar)
    {
        NodoCorecto->Cantidad = NodoCorecto->Cantidad + CantidadMas;
        printf("Se le agrego la cantidad adicional al inventario!\n");
        break;
    }

    else
    {
      NodoCorecto = NodoCorecto->Siguiente;
    }
  }

  if (NodoCorecto == NULL)
  {
    printf("No se encontro producto con ese codigo.\n");
  }
}


void Retirar(Lista *lista, int Restar, int CantidadMenos)
{
  RegistroProducto *NodoCorecto = lista->Primero;

  while (NodoCorecto != NULL)
  {
    if (NodoCorecto->Codigo == Restar)
    {
      if (NodoCorecto->Cantidad - CantidadMenos >= 0)
      {
        NodoCorecto->Cantidad = NodoCorecto->Cantidad - CantidadMenos;
        printf("Se le retiro la cantidad saliendo del inventario!\n");
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        printf("Se encontro el producto, pero esta restando más de la cantidad del producto que usted dispone.\n");
        printf("Porfavor intente de nuevo.\n\n");
        break;
      }

    }

    else
    {
      NodoCorecto = NodoCorecto->Siguiente;
    }
  }

  if (NodoCorecto == NULL)
  {
    printf("No se encontro producto con ese codigo.\n");
  }
}




void guardarInventario()
{
  FILE *archivo;

  archivo = fopen("Inventario.txt", "w+");
  if(archivo == NULL)
  {
    printf("\n Error en el archivo\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Se ha abierto el archivo.\n");

    char *PdcNombre, PdcFecha;
    int PdcCantidad, PdcCodigo;
    float PdcPrecio; 

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(Insercion); i++)
    {
    fprintf(archivo,"\n Nombre: %[^\n]\n Codigo: %d \n Cantidad: %d \n Precio: %f \nFecha: %[^\n]",PdcNombre,PdcCodigo,PdcCantidad,PdcPrecio,PdcFecha);
    }
  }
  fclose(archivo);
}


int Tabla()
{
  printf("\n¿Que deasea hacer?\n");
  printf("1) Registro de productos.\n");
  printf("2) Ingreso de productos.\n");
  printf("3) Salida de productos.\n");
  printf("4) Reporte de inventario.\n");
  printf("5) Salir.\n");

  int Opcion;
  scanf("%d", &Opcion);
  return(Opcion);
}


int main()
{

Lista *miLista = Inicialisacion();

guardarInventario();

int Opcion;
Opcion = Tabla();

while (Opcion != 5)
{
  if (Opcion > 5 || Opcion < 1)
  {
    printf("Entrada invalida\n");
    Opcion = Tabla();
  }

  if (Opcion == 1)
  {
    char PdcNombre[100];
    printf("¿Cual es el nombre del producto? ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", PdcNombre);

    int PdcCodigo, PdcCantidad;
    float PdcPrecio;

    printf("¿Cual es el codigo del producto? ");
    scanf("%d", &PdcCodigo);
    printf("¿Cual es la cantidad del producto? ");
    scanf("%d", &PdcCantidad);
    printf("¿Cual es el precio del producto? ");
    scanf("%f", &PdcPrecio);

    char PdcFecha[20];
    printf("Ingrese la fecha (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", PdcFecha);


    Insercion(miLista, PdcNombre, PdcFecha, PdcCodigo, PdcCantidad, PdcPrecio);

    guardarInventario();

    Opcion = Tabla();

  }

  if (Opcion == 2)
  {
    printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto entrando: ");
    int Sumar, CantidadMas;
    scanf("%d", &Sumar);

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad cual esta entrando: ");
    scanf("%d", &CantidadMas);

    Anadir(miLista, Sumar, CantidadMas);

    Opcion = Tabla();
  }

  if (Opcion == 3)
  {
    printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto saliendo: ");
    int Restar, CantidadMenos;
    scanf("%d", &Restar);

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad cual esta saliendo: ");
    scanf("%d", &CantidadMenos);

    Retirar(miLista, Restar, CantidadMenos);

    Opcion = Tabla();
  }

  if (Opcion == 4)
  {
    printf("El inventario completo es:\n\n");

    PrintLista(miLista);

    Opcion = Tabla();
  }

}

if (Opcion == 5)
{
  printf("Feliz día.\n");
  return 0;
}

}```


el output del archivo es:


 Nombre: %[^
]
 Codigo: 28304000 
 Cantidad: 32766 
 Precio: -0.000000 
Fecha: %[^
]
````

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores en el programa que pueden producir *memory leaks*, pero la respuesta a tu pregunta está en tu función `guardarInventario()`.

```
char *PdcNombre, PdcFecha;
int PdcCantidad, PdcCodigo;
float PdcPrecio; 

for(int i=0; i<sizeof(Insercion); i++)
{
    fprintf(archivo,"\n Nombre: %[^\n]\n Codigo: %d \n Cantidad: %d \n Precio: %f \nFecha: %[^\n]",PdcNombre,PdcCodigo,PdcCantidad,PdcPrecio,PdcFecha);
}
```

1. `Insercion` es una función, de modo que la llamada `sizeof(Insercion)` no te devolverá lo que necesitas.
2. cuando invocas a la función `fprintf(...)`, los argumentos que estás utilizando no están inicializados, de modo que tendrán unos valores que corresponderán a lo que había en el *stack* antes de invocar a la función.

La solución está en pasar el puntero a tu lista de inventario a la función `guardarInventario()` y luego iterar sobre ella de la forma en que lo haces para sumar y restar, pero tratando a todos los elementos. Para llamar a la función `fprintf(...)` entonces utilizarías los valores de la entrada sobre la que en ese momento estés.

Creo que lo podrás hacer sin problemas, pero si necesitas más ayuda, pon simplemente un comentario a esta respuesta.

Comment: Gracias! si me ayudo bastante! Ahora si se copian los datos! Sin embargo, si ingresó otro producto solo me sale ese último producto ingresado.

Comment: ¿Tienes forma de compartir el nuevo código para darle un vistazo?